# Proof by induction for a complex matrix raised to the 4n power.

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I have been practicing proof by induction, and attempted the following problem (question in red, my attempt in green). However, I am unsure with this is rigorous, and would greatly appreciate if someone can verify my proof, especially the inductive step. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Consider using MathJax instead of images, that way it will be more search engines friendly in the future, plus images might cause issues on smaller devices. Looking at your other posts you already have it in some posts (including matrices), so it shouldn't be such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

If you wished you could make more use of the identity matrix viz.

$$A^{4(k+1)}=A^{4k}A^{4}=(-4)^kI(-4)I=(-4)^{k+1}I.$$